# Dynamic tabs and data display in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to dynamically creating tabs in tab panel based on the number of rows. The drop down to select the number of records per page will determine how many records to show. Say there are 20 records in the result set and the records per page is 5 then there will be 4 tabs provided. And if there are 15 records in the result set and records per page is 4 there will be 4 tabs with 3 in the last tab.
Each tab should have the data as per the row numbers falling in that page.

**Questions**:

1. How should the dynamic generation of tabs be done.
2. How to dynamically assign the relevant contents of each tab (based on number of records per page).

```
# Loading the packages
v_lst_packages <- c("data.table",'shinydashboard','shiny', 'dplyr')
a = lapply(v_lst_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
#-------------------------
# creating a test sample data table for testing
lst1 = rep (c('Apple','Mango','Pinapple','Banana'), 10)
set.seed(001) # just to make it reproducible
lst1 = sample(lst1)
lst2 = rep (c('Flt1','Flt2','Flt3','Flt4'), 10)
set.seed(002)
lst2 = sample(lst2)
lst3 = rep(c('a','b','c','d'),10)
set.seed(003)
lst3=sample(lst3)
dt_src_tbl <- data.table(Col1=lst1,  Col2=lst2, Col3=lst3)
v_lst_col1 = unique(unlist(dt_src_tbl$Col1))
v_lst_col2 = unique(unlist(dt_src_tbl$Col2))

# Creating the list of number of records per page
v_lst_records_per_page = c(2,4,6,10)
#--------------------------------------------
#Writing Ui of the application
ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('MainPage',
             selectInput("par_col1", "Col1", v_lst_col1, multiple = T),
             selectInput("par_col2", "Col2", v_lst_col2, multiple = T),
             selectInput("par_records_per_page",'Rows per SubTab',v_lst_records_per_page,multiple = F),
             textOutput('v_row_count_op'),
             tabsetPanel(tabPanel("SubTab1",
                                  tableOutput("dt_src_tbl_fltr_op"))))))

#--------------------------------------------
# Writing Server of page
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Filtering data with equal filter
    dt_src_tbl_fltr <- reactive(
        dt_src_tbl %>%
            filter(Col1 %in% req(input$par_col1))%>% filter(Col2 %in% req(input$par_col2)))
    output$dt_src_tbl_fltr_op <- renderTable(dt_src_tbl_fltr())
    output$v_row_count_op <- renderText(paste0("There are ",as.character(nrow(dt_src_tbl_fltr())),
                                               " Rows. ",as.character(input$par_records_per_page),' per SubTab.',
                                               " Number of SubTabs ",as.character(
                                                   ceiling(nrow(dt_src_tbl_fltr())/
                                                                                  as.numeric(input$par_records_per_page)))))
}

shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: "And if there are 15 records in the result set and records per page is 4 there will be 4 tabs with 1 in the last tab." Why not four tabs with three rows in the last tab?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I have updated same...